# git modifying code on multiple branches using the same eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I kind of feel I am missing something here, but here is the question.
I have a branch A. Work is in progress in this branch. A tag T is created which marks a production release version. Now, a fix has to be done on top of the code in this tag. So I created a branch B out of the tag. The branch would contain stable production code.
My eclipse points to checked-out code in branch A.

Now, I want to make changes to code in branch B. How can I make my eclipse realize that there are 2 different branches and the code is different?
Do I have to clone the branch B and point a new eclipse workspace to it?
Cant I use the same workspace and have 2 different versions of the same file - one from branch A and another from Branch B?

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout branch B in your workspace, make your changes, commit, and then you can checkout again branch A and continue to work on branch A. Eclipse will automatically recognize the content of the other branch
However, you should be aware, that you shouldn't have uncommitted changes in your workspace, when you checkout another branch. Either commit your changes or stash, before checkout.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have eclipse integrated with your git system, you can use select the project you are working on, and then in the context menu, use "Team->Switch To->New Branch...", and choose branch B.

[image]

if you don't have it integrated, you can do so with the following 2 steps.

using the *git perspective*, in the **Git Repositories** view, find the icon with the + to perform *Add an existing local Git Repository to this view* .

[image]
in the subsequent dialog, choose the location of your repository.

once it's added, go back to your *java perspective*, and from there, select the project in git (which you currently have in branch A), and from the context menu, select **Team->Share Project**

[image]